# google script error Range not found (line 6, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function getTotalSum(cell) {
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length ; i++ ) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var val = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();
    if (typeof(val) == 'number') {
        sum += val;   
    }       
}
return sum;
```

}

I keep getting error running this code. the error is Range not found (line 6) . What is the work around for this error?

Comment: Can we ask you about the value of ``cell`` that you gave?

Comment: I haven't declare a cell value, but i would like the cell to be the cell that will be sum across all sheets

Comment: Because the value of cell is not declared, the error in your question occurs.

Comment: I haven't declare a cell value, but i would like the cell to be user define and  will be sum across all sheets

Comment: how would i come to declare this cell value?

Comment: Do you want to use this function as a custom function on the Spreadsheet? Do you want to make users use the custom function? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to be able to sum a cell across all sheets without having to reference each sheet

Comment: In order to use a range as a value, please enclose the range in double quotes like ``"A1"``. If you use ``A1`` as a custom function, the value of ``A1`` is used. It's not range. By this, the error occurs. So, for example, can you try to put ``=getTotalSum("A1")`` to a cell?

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! Could you please help me with another issue? how do i exclude certain sheet that i don't want to sum ?

Comment: Do you know the index or sheet name you want to exclude?

Comment: Yes i have sheet names.

Comment: Can I ask you about the sheet names?

Comment: it is "SUMMARY", "TOTAL", and "MASTER"

Comment: I posted the modified script. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the modified script. This script calculates by excluding the sheet names you set.

```
function getTotalSum(cell) {
  var excludesheets = ["SUMMARY", "TOTAL", "MASTER"]; // Added
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length ; i++ ) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if (!~excludesheets.indexOf(sheet.getName())) { // Added
      var val = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();
      if (typeof(val) == 'number') {
        sum += val;   
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

### Edit : Automatically recalculate of custom function including values of other sheets

In order to make spreadsheet recalculate, it is required to let it know that the value was changed. But at `=getTotalSum("A1")` for giving the range, even if the value of `"A1"` was changed, the range of `"A1"` is not changed. As a result, the recalculation is not run.

As one of several workarounds, I thought that it lets spreadsheet know the change of the cell value by giving the coordinate of cell.

- For example, when you use `=getTotalSum("A1")` to sum each "A1" of "sheet1", "sheet2" and "sheet3", please modify to `=getTotalSum("A1", sheet1!A1, sheet2!A1, sheet3!A1)`.

#### Note :

- You are not required to modify the script of my answer.

  - `sheet1!A1, sheet2!A1, sheet3!A1` is not used for the custom function. This is used only to let spreadsheet know the change of cell value.
- By giving `sheet1!A1, sheet2!A1, sheet3!A1`, when one of each "A1" is changed, spreadsheet can know the change and recalculates.

Comment: It is still adding values from the "TOTALS" sheet. How can i fix this?Also, Whenever i edit something in one of the sheet, how can i have the formula to automatically refresh itself rather than me having to delete and retype all the equation for it to refresh?

Comment: @kate I'm sorry for the inconvenience. At your comment, you said it is ``"SUMMARY"``, ``"TOTAL"``, and ``"MASTER"``. So I used ``var excludesheets = ["SUMMARY", "TOTAL", "MASTER"];``. If you changed the name from ``"TOTAL"`` to ``"TOTALS"``, please modify from ``var excludesheets = ["SUMMARY", "TOTAL", "MASTER"];`` to ``var excludesheets = ["SUMMARY", "TOTALS", "MASTER"];``. If this didn't work, can you show us your sample sheet?

Comment: I found a workaround which is to just move my columns that i have value in "Total" to a different column to avoid the number being added. Is there a way i can have it refresh automatically when i edit a value in any of the sheet? Here is the link to my sample workbook: https://docs.google.com/a/bluestarvending.com/spreadsheets/d/1HRRCQFGv6g3N65SbZI138IB7SSU1pf1Hw3TT7zlQ7F0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you it is working properly now! but The whole purpose that I have this function is to sum all the sheets even when new sheet is added then it will automatically sum the value from that new sheet as well. If i reference it =getTotalSum("A1", sheet1!A1, sheet2!A1, sheet3!A1) then every time i have a new sheet added i would have to reference it. I want i way where it can automatically reference all sheets even when new sheet is added. Is there a way to do this by any chance?

Comment: @kate In this workaround, unfortunately, it cannot do that. When new sheets are inserted, the script has to be also modified, if you don't want to exclude the calculation at the new sheets. I'm sorry I couldn't notice that you will insert new sheets from your question. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Tanaike i was able to solve this problem by using indirect. You helped guide me down the right direction though! thank you so much!

Comment: @kate Thank you for additional information. If you post your solution as updating your question, other users who have the same problem will be also useful.